# Create external table in Greenplum using parquet file stored in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, greenplum, external-tables

I am trying to create an external table in Greenplum database on an Amazon ec2-cluster. My source file is parquet and stored in s3. 
My question is:

What protocol should I use to read the data from the parquet file?

If I use "s3://" with file format "Parquet" as below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE rp2 (id text, fname text, lname text, mname text) LOCATION ('s3://location.parquet config=./s3/s3.config')
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  unexpected end of file  (seg0 slice1 IP:port pid=xxx)
```

If I go for gphdfs:// protocol as :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE rp2 (id text, fname text, lname text, mname text) LOCATION ('gphdfs:location.parquet config=./s3/s3.config') FORMAT 'PARQUET';
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  external table gphdfs protocol command ended with error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal input uri: gphdfs://locs.parquet config=./s3/s3.config  (seg0 slice1 IP:Port pid=pid)
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: We are working on this too...I consider using pxf, like ````pxf://S3_BUCKET/pxf_examples/my_file?PROFILE=s3:parquet&SERVER=s3srvcfg````
from here https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5170/pxf/access_objstore.html . Because s3 protocol do not support parquet format

Answer (score 1):

You can read parquet file on S3 by using [PXF](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5170/pxf/access_objstore.html)

Example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pxf_ext_tbl(name text, orders int)
  LOCATION ('pxf://S3_BUCKET/dir/file.parquet?PROFILE=s3:parquet&SERVER=s3srvcfg)
 FORMAT 'CUSTOM' (FORMATTER='pxfwritable_import');
```